# How to calculate number of revolutions made by user arround a GPS location in android

Tags: android, gps

I want to calculate number of times user passes by a location.

What i am doing right now is:
I am saving user's current `GPS location` when starts. and in `onLocationChanged`i am calculating distance from my saved location. if distance is less than a meter i am counting it as one round.
But it is not that much accurate,

Is there any other option available?

Comment: round = circle or just steps ?

Comment: complete circle, Same like revolution or CIRCUMAMBULATION

Comment: this will be a little complex. would you mind discussing it on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) ?

Comment: dont have enough reputations.. sorry @Shubhank

Comment: any one there for help?

Comment: hey, still can't chat. can you ? maybe post a bounty for it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113935/discussion-between-android-priya-and-shubhank).